# Enable unmanaged code debugging in Windows Phone 8.1 Unit Test project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, c++-cli, windows-phone-8.1, c++-cx

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 C++/CX project and a Windows Phone 8.1 XAML Unit Tests C# project. The unit tests project references the C++/CX project. I want to be able to debug the C++/CX code when running the tests in debug.

All the answers on how to do this I found mention enabling `Enable unmanaged code debugging` on the `Debug` tab of the project preferences. But the problem, there is no debug tab in my project:

[image]

Is it even possible to debug C++/CX code in Windows Phone 8.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible in a Windows Phone 8.1 XAML Unit Tests C# project, only in a Windows Phone 8.1 XAML project. So you need to create a Windows Phone 8.1 XAML project and copy the unit tests to this project, not really an elegant solution.